# What does mmap actually return?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm a little confused as to how to define the address an mmap call actually returns probably because I saw a piece of code where this address is converted to `uint64_t` and used as a physical address.
If it is a virtual address, and we need a physical address can it be found out using a formula where a modulo with the pagesize etc is involved after opening proc/self/map. Just being abstract with it.

Does it matter how we treat this address with or without hugepages?

Also, if what kind of address is suitable for being classified as a DMA-ABLE address. Going over through code samples, in kernel we use `pci_alloc_consistent` and `pci_map_single` to find the dma addresses. Suppose in a userspace application, I wish to dma TO/FROM device and allocate a portion of memory via malloc or mmap for its tx and rx rings and I want the physical address associated with this address. Should I just use type conversion `uint64_t(addr)`  or write a function to convert this virtual address to physical address equivalent to a dma handle returned by pci alloc consistent.

Adding a sample from Open Source DPDK Code

```
    mcfg = rte_eal_get_configuration()->mem_config;

/* hugetlbfs can be disabled */
if (internal_config.no_hugetlbfs) {
    addr = mmap(NULL, internal_config.memory, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
            MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);
    if (addr == MAP_FAILED) {
        RTE_LOG(ERR, EAL, "%s: mmap() failed: %s\n", __func__,
                strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    mcfg->memseg[0].phys_addr = (phys_addr_t)(uintptr_t)addr;  -----???
    mcfg->memseg[0].addr = addr;
    mcfg->memseg[0].len = internal_config.memory;
    mcfg->memseg[0].socket_id = SOCKET_ID_ANY;
    return 0;
}
```

In the other case it would convert the address mmaped from hugepages to a physical address via this.

```
    /*
 * Get physical address of any mapped virtual address in the current process.
 */
phys_addr_t
rte_mem_virt2phy(const void *virtaddr)
{
    int fd;
    uint64_t page, physaddr;
    unsigned long virt_pfn;
    int page_size;
    off_t offset;

    /* standard page size */
    page_size = getpagesize();

    fd = open("/proc/self/pagemap", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        RTE_LOG(ERR, EAL, "%s(): cannot open /proc/self/pagemap: %s\n",
            __func__, strerror(errno));
        return RTE_BAD_PHYS_ADDR;
    }

    virt_pfn = (unsigned long)virtaddr / page_size;
    offset = sizeof(uint64_t) * virt_pfn;
    if (lseek(fd, offset, SEEK_SET) == (off_t) -1) {
        RTE_LOG(ERR, EAL, "%s(): seek error in /proc/self/pagemap: %s\n",
                __func__, strerror(errno));
        close(fd);
        return RTE_BAD_PHYS_ADDR;
    }
    if (read(fd, &page, sizeof(uint64_t)) < 0) {
        RTE_LOG(ERR, EAL, "%s(): cannot read /proc/self/pagemap: %s\n",
                __func__, strerror(errno));
        close(fd);
        return RTE_BAD_PHYS_ADDR;
    }

    /*
     * the pfn (page frame number) are bits 0-54 (see
     * pagemap.txt in linux Documentation)
     */
    physaddr = ((page & 0x7fffffffffffffULL) * page_size)
        + ((unsigned long)virtaddr % page_size);
    close(fd);
    return physaddr;
}
```

Comment: There might not *be* a physical address...

Comment: I can't see anmy mmp option that mentions returning the physical address of the mapped memory, only the virtual address, are you sure that the result wan no being passed to something capable of converting virtual addresses into physical addreses?

Comment: I just edited with examples. Can you help me with that now?

Comment: this is kernel driver code?  this may clarify things: http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch13.html

Answer (score 2):

`mmap()` returns a pointer into the newly mapped memory. This pointer points into the address space seen by the program and can be used like any other pointer of type `void*`. On failure, `mmap()` returns `MAP_FAILED` which is a constant that has typically the value `(void*)-1`.

Comment: I am having a similar implementation. I am getting the return address as 0XFFFFFFFFFFFFF. This is obviously wrong. Can you tell me the possible reason? I have checked the values being passed ..Thanks

Comment: @john This is `MAP_FAILED`. Inspect `errno` for the error source.

Comment: I have added `if(!mapped_data)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"Failed in npheap_alloc()\n");
            exit(1);
        }` . but instead of going in this condition, it is returning an address. How to further debug this. i tried printing `EXIT_FAILURE` as well. Also the `kern log` is not showing any failure

Comment: @john Note that `!mapped_data` is equal to `mapped_data == 0`. This doesn't work as you want to test for `-1`. Try this: `if (mapped_data == MAP_FAILED) { perror("npheap_alloc()"); exit(1); }`. This should also print the reason for the error. Please consider asking a separate question.

Comment: It worked, error is `resource currently unavailable`. you are right I can start a new thred,  was avoiding it being marked as duplicate .. thanks

Comment: which header file defines `MAP_FAILED`?

Comment: @Potion According to POSIX, [sys/mman.h](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_mman.h.html).

Answer (score 1):

mmap() returns a virtual address created by remap_pfn_range for a particular physical address and length.
You can get the physical addr using virt_to_phys(). Ofcourse this does the same kind of job like modulo with page size etc but completely architecture dependent as MMU is implemented subjective to architecture.

Bus address is used to DMA data to hardware. pci_alloc_consistent etc functions returns you two addresses.
1. Virtual address
2. Bus address.

Your driver can address a physical chunk of RAM using virtual memory. Because the MMU converts virt_to_phys while CPU is executing that instruction. But during a DMA operation, the CPU is bypassed and the device cannot address using a virtual address. The device is inserted on an interface (like PCI slot) which is connected to the bus (like PCI bus). Hence it can address only using a bus address.
The defacto condition for using the bus address is the corresponding pages of memory should not be swapped out. pci_alloc_consistent does that.
As long as we have consistent mappings, we can DMA without issue.

uint64_t(addr) doesn't yield you physical addr from a virtual addr. Instead use virt_to_phys(). I dont understand why you need a physical address when you can address using virt and bus addresses in this case. Still if it is required, use it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I require a bus address because I'm trying to DMA from user space instead of kernel space where calls like bus_to_virt etc are easily available. SO the ring descriptors, get memory via mmap and the dma address is also required later. How do I get a dma address from user space?

Answer (score 1):

As others have answered, mmap() returns a virtual address.  If you need the physical address (e.g. for a user space dma driver), then you can convert 
virtual to physical using by reading /proc/self/pagemap and doing page frame 
number math such as is done by the cited DPDK example.  There are a couple of caveats that you need to be aware of:

- Depending on kernel version, the page frame number bits may or may not be valid (check Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt for details)
- The mmap operation alone may not be sufficient for the kernel to reserve physical memory.  Accessing the memory (via read|write|lock) should cause a page fault that will prompt the kernel to reserve the physical memory.
- If you need more than one page size of memory, then more work may be required - like using hugepages or implementing something like what DPDK does to sort memory by physical address, then remap virtual addresses so that both physical and virtual memory are contiguous.
- In order for virtual to physical mapping to remain valid, pages must not get swapped out of memory by the kernel.  DPDK handles this by mlock()ing each page.